# Remove empty Object from JSON arrays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove this empty key value pair object from this JSON array but it I am unable to figure out on how to do it.

I tried this:

```
var array = {
  "title":[
    {"lang":"English","value":"yes"},
    {"lang":"Spanish","value":"no"},
    {"lang":"German","value":""}
  ]
}
var result =  array['title'].filter(function(x){return x.length});
```

This gives the following output:

```
{
  "title":[
    {"lang":"English","value":"yes"},
    {"lang":"Spanish","value":"no"},
    {"lang":"German"}
  ]
}
```

Output expected:

```
{
  "title":[
    {"lang":"English","value":"yes"},
    {"lang":"Spanish","value":"no"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your filter to look for an empty string in the value property:

```js
var array = {
  "title": [{
      "lang": "English",
      "value": "yes"
    },
    {
      "lang": "Spanish",
      "value": "no"
    }, {
      "lang": "German",
      "value": ""
    }
  ]
}
var result = array['title'].filter(x=>x.value !== "");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.

```
array['title'].filter( element => element.value )
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying what it's looking for for each element.

Try changing your filter function to check if the value exists and has a length greater than 0:

```js
function(x) { return x.value && x.value.length > 0 }
```